# Stellar Core Stuck at Catching up or Joining SCP

Tags: stellar-core

I'm trying to get a basic version of Stellar Core setup in Docker using the [`stellar/quickstart`](https://hub.docker.com/r/stellar/quickstart) image.

One of the problems I'm running into tho is that the `state` is stuck at `Catching up` or `Joining SCP`. It seems like it's making progress and new ledgers are being added, but most of the time it's still `Catching up` or `Joining SCP`.

There was one time I saw it at `Synced!`, but a few seconds later it went back to `Catching up` or `Joining SCP`.

The `status` does change frequently between different tasks, so it does seem like it's trying to get caught up and synced with everything, but it's almost like the network is moving faster than Stellar Core can keep up. I'm running this on a Mac Mini tho, which seems to have enough power for other tasks, so I'd be pretty surprised if it isn't up for handling this. And if that is the case then running Stellar Core requires an extremely powerful machine to run.

Is this normal? If not, any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Other people were having this issue with quickstart. Seems like something is wrong with the default setting for minimal catchup. Try setting catchup complete to false and catchup recent to 1024 in your config. I know this solved the issue for others.